# fwrite outputs character string incorrectly

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, fwrite, fread

I am currently writing a C++ program to control some LEDs by sending strings via termios to an Arduino. Each line is ended by a newline character. I have written a test program that would output to the terminal, but there are issues with the output of the following code snippet:

```
char* ledAddr = (char*)malloc(3);
char* rVal = (char*)malloc(3);
char* gVal = (char*)malloc(3);
char* bVal = (char*)malloc(3);
...
fread(ledAddr, 3, 1, stdin);
fread(rVal, 3, 1, stdin);
fread(gVal, 3, 1, stdin);
fread(bVal, 3, 1, stdin);
...
char* outputString = malloc(17);

outputString[0] = 't';
strncpy(outputString+1, rVal, 3);
outputString[4] = ',';
strncpy(outputString+5, gVal, 3);
outputString[8] = ',';
strncpy(outputString+9, bVal, 3);
outputString[12] = ',';
strncpy(outputString+13, ledAddr, 3);
outputString[16] = '\n'

fwrite(outputString, 17, 1, stdout);
```

This is my test input:

```
180
255
0
0
```

This is my expected output:

```
t255,0,0,180
```

And this is what I wind up with:

```
t
25,5
0,0,
184
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct to me. You probably wanted to skip the newlines but `fread()` won't do that for you. If you wanted the `FILE` operations to read lines, you'd use `fgets()` rather than `fread()`.

Comment: You're right, I had forgotten to take into account that `fread()` doesn't skip newlines. It works correctly now.